# Necessary user info when publishing to AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, publish

I want to publish an app to AppStore.
The app is based on HTML/CSS/JS and basically just a WebView which loads local web content.
Nothing is being collected as user info or anything else.
The only thing that needs Internet connection is the AdMob banner to be shown.

In order not to get rejected, what are the necessary information I should add to my app?

*e.g. Should there be a button to show a pop-up with some text saying no user data is being collected?*

*e.g. Is there any mandatory GDPR text I should present to the user?*

Answer (score 0):

Add the info at splash screen and show popup to open settings and open wifi. Most probably apple rejects on webview apps. If got rejected then add push notification feature also.